# Remote-control or video-stream a closed-computer-system with another computer (no VNC)?

Tags: video, remote, remote-desktop

I have two computers next to each other (A - test computer, B - recorder/remote client). I need to be able to either: remote control computer A from computer B, or record and project/stream video out from computer A to computer B (with KVM switch for mouse/keyboard control).

The problem is that I can not make any changes to computer A. It is completely closed system. Could be windows, could be Linux. If it will be Linux, it is not guarantied that VNC server can be installed and configured. Similar things for permissions either on Linux or Windows.

Is capture card the only way to project/stream video output from computer A on computer B?